# Mute Role Saves To The Muted User When They Leave From The Server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, quick.db

**This is my code but when someone i gave Mute role if he leave the server and re join it the role disappear, When I am using quick.db it is not working what should I do to make it work**

````js
const ms = require('ms')
const timer = new Map();
client.on('message', async nxt => {
  if (nxt.content.startsWith(prefix + "role")){
    var args = nxt.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        if(!nxt.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')) return nxt.channel.send("You don't have permissions")
        var member = nxt.mentions.members.first();
        var time = args[3]
        var role = nxt.mentions.roles.first();
        if(!role) return nxt.channel.send("I Can't find this role")
        if(!member) return nxt.channel.send("Please Mention Someone")
        if(!time) return nxt.channel.send("Please specify a time")
        if (!time.endsWith("d")) {
        if (!time.endsWith("h")) {
        if (!time.endsWith("m")) {
        if (!time.endsWith("s")) {
          return nxt.channel.send('Please specify a time')
        }}}}
    timer.set(nxt.author.id,{
      author: {
        tag: nxt.author.tag,
      },
      time: ms(time),
    });
        await member.roles.add(role)
        nxt.react(`✅`)
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await member.roles.remove(role)
           timer.delete(nxt.author.id);
        }, ms(time))
 }});```

How can I make it to give the mute role back ?
````

Answer (score 0):

First add this line in your code

```js
//using quick.db
let muteTime = Date.now() + time;
db.set(`muted_${message.guild.id}_${target.id}`, muteTime);
```

Then when a member joins do this

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    let MuteStatus = db.get(`muted_${member.guild.id}_${member.id}`);
    if(!MuteStatus){
        //This member wasn't muted
        return(0);
    }
    if(MuteStatus > Date.now()){
        //He was muted and rejoined
        //Give the role back
       let TimeLeft = MuteStatus - Date.now();
       await member.roles.add(MuteRole) //Give the muted role
       setTimeout(async () => {
            await member.roles.remove(MuteRole);
        },TimeLeft);
    }
});
```

Comment: i did that bro thanks for helping but the problem is noting happing when some one rejoin the server the bot is not given the mute role back :/